# Why objects render black even when a texture is applied in blender?

Tags: rendering

I created several objects ,applied its material with texture .But still when I render the scene all render nicely except one.It renders black both in cycles and BI.I have tried everything .I don't know whether I have missed something or not But I'm not getting the result properly.What is the solution to this 'rendering black' problem ?

Please help
Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Are you talking about Blender? I'm guessing based on your mention of "cycles". You might have more luck at [blender.se] then.

Comment: Yes , Thanks @delnan  -I'd better edit the question .